# How do I use two different versions of jQuery side by side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-1.5, jquery-1.4

I'm writing a wrapper for Yahoo Web Analytics at work. My wrapper has jQuery 1.5.3 built-in, while the page where I'm installing the wrapper uses jQuery 1.4.3. When I include my wrapper, their site fails, due to what I'm guessing is the updated Ajax functions in jQuery 1.5.3.

Is there any way I can include jQuery without overwriting the previously included jQuery scripts?

---

Them upgrading their page is unfortunately not an option. Neither is downgrading our tracking script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var $yournamespece = jQuery.noConflict(true);
// now use $yournamespace instead of $
$yournamespace('selector')
```

Though I'm curious as to what your script uses that is not compatible with their version...1.5 hasn't really been out all *that* long

Comment: If I may ask, how will that work? If my script has already overwritten jQuëry 1.4.3 with jQuery 1.5.3, calling noconflict surely won't turn back time?

Comment: getJSON is just a wrapper for $.ajax, not hard to fix that. Big change with it is JSON.parse is used in the newer version, but should not make any difference.

Comment: @Codemonkey: I'm not 100% on the internals of jQuery but I believe it starts out by copying the $ namespace to another namespace before doing anything, so that if you do use .noConflict(), it copies itself into the specified namespace and copies the backup to the $ namespace, effectively "giving it back" to the previous library. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: I actually had to make a small edit to the code, passing `true`, based on the following link I provided. It says: "*If necessary, we can free up the jQuery name as well by passing true as an argument to the method. This is rarely necessary, and if we must do this (for example, if we need to **use multiple versions of the jQuery library on the same page**), we need to consider that most plug-ins rely on the presence of the jQuery variable and may not operate correctly in this situation.*"